# How to append rows to a Pandas dataframe, and have it turn multiple overlapping cells (with the same index) into a single value, instead of a series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am appending different dataframes to make one set. Occasionally, some values have the same index, so it stores the value as a series. Is there a quick way within Pandas to just overwrite the value instead of storing all the values as a series?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your dataframe (maybe a few rows of relevant columns) and then an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't very clear guy. If you want to resolve the duplicated indexes problem, probably the `pd.Dataframe.reset_index()` method will be enough. But, if you have duplicate rows when you concat the Dataframes, just use the `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` method. Else, share a bit of your code with or be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the code below is what you're searching.
we say two dataframes, one columns, the same index and different values. and you wanna overwrite the value in one dataframe with the other. you can do it with a simple loop with `iloc` indexer.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['a','b','c','d']})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['q','w','e','r']})

rows = df_1.shape[0]

for idx in range(rows):
    df_1['col_1'].iloc[idx] = df_2['col_2'].iloc[idx]
```

Then, you check the df_1. you should get that:

```
df_1

  col_1
0     q
1     w
2     e
3     r
```

Whatever the response is what you want, let me know so I can help you.